# Customize place of start scripts in gradle build

Tags: java, gradle

I'm new to gradle any trying to package a little project of mine. When building my distribution package, the structure is as follows:

```
my-project.zip
|
+- my-project
   |
   +- bin (containing start scripts)
   +- lib
   +- xyz (folders from src/dist)
```

What I want to achieve is having the start scripts in the project root folder instead of the `bin` subfolder (I know that this is some kind of convention, but I also like to start my application from within the application folder):

```
my-project.zip
|
+- my-project
   |
   +- lib
   +- xyz (folders from src/dist)
   +- my-project.bat
   +- my-project.sh
```

Is this possible?

I've tried setting `tasks.startScripts.outputDir` but with no success (scripts were completely removed from the distribution package).

**Update**

In addition to lu.koerfer's answer I had to modify the start scripts to take into account the changed APP_HOME:

```
startScripts {
    startScripts.applicationName = artefactsBaseName
    doLast {
        def windowsScriptFile = file getWindowsScript()
        def unixScriptFile = file getUnixScript()
        windowsScriptFile.text = windowsScriptFile.text.replace('set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%..', 'set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%')
        unixScriptFile.text = unixScriptFile.text.replace('cd "`dirname \"$PRG\"`/.." >/dev/null', 'cd "`dirname \"$PRG\"`" >/dev/null')
    }
}
```

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using `java`, `application` and `eclipse`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to care about the creation of the start scripts (the `startScripts` task), but about the creation of the zip file (the `distZip` task) to control where the files will be put. For this purpose, you could directly use the `distZip` task or the [`DistributionContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/distribution/DistributionContainer.html) from the Gradle Distribution plugin, which is automatically applied with the Gradle Application plugin. The `DistributionContainer` allows you to manage the creation of multiple distributions in your Gradle project and the Application plugin uses the `main` distribution by default.

```
distributions.main {
    contents {
        from startScripts
    }
}
```

This piece of code simply adds the outputs of the `startScripts` tasks to the `main` distribution contents. They will be placed in the root folder of this distribution, since you did not specify a child `CopySpec` with an `into` method.

I assume that you want your start scripts **only** in the root folder, but not in the `bin` folder as well. Since you can only exclude files of a `Copy` task based on their source path and not on their destination path, you'll need to exclude them when they are copied, via the `eachFile` method (because then their destination is known):

```
distZip {
    eachFile { file ->
        if (file.path.contains('bin')) {
            file.exclude()
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this piece of code will remove the whole `bin` directory from the zip file, so you could need to redescribe the condition in the closure for other use cases.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

For Gradle v8 the scripts have changed a bit. So, to set the `APP_HOME` properly I had do this:

```
startScripts {
    doLast {
        def windowsScriptFile = file getWindowsScript()
        def unixScriptFile = file getUnixScript()

        windowsScriptFile.text = windowsScriptFile.text.replace('set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%..', 'set APP_HOME=%DIRNAME%')
        unixScriptFile.text = unixScriptFile.text.replace('APP_HOME=$( cd "${APP_HOME:-./}.." && pwd -P ) || exit', 'APP_HOME=$( cd "${APP_HOME:-./}" && pwd -P ) || exit')
    }
}
```